# how to add product items to cart in flutter e commerce appication

Tags: json, flutter

iam trying to add the product items to cart screen but unable to do that. can any one please help me

After clicking on add button i want to show the item in cart screen and also before checking it in cart it will show the notification the item is added to cart tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you clear, you are trying to build a cart app.
please reference this https://github.com/hupptechnologies/shopping-app-with-cart-flutter-demo

you can see demo picture has a "Add to Cart" button. and append selected product to Cart List.

[image]

Comment: but in my case i have  product list api and additem to cart ,get cart apis.i want add the product and also increment the quantity of the product using rest apis

Comment: I suggest you post this part in another question and provide your json string. It would be easier for someone has same problem to search and help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          //TODO: to fix the issue
          stream: EcommerceApp.firestore
              .collection("items")
              .where("shortInfo",
                  isEqualTo: EcommerceApp.sharedPreferences
                      .getStringList(EcommerceApp.userCartList)[i])
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return !snapshot.hasData
                ? SliverToBoxAdapter(
                    child: Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    ),
                  )
                : snapshot.data.docs.length == 0
                    ? beginBuildingCart()
                    : SliverList(
                        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                          (context, index) {
                            ItemModel model = ItemModel.fromJson(
                              snapshot.data.docs[index].data(),
                            );
                            if (index == 1) {
                              totalAmount = 0;
                              totalAmount = model.price + totalAmount;
                            } else {
                              totalAmount = model.price + totalAmount;
                            }

                            if (snapshot.data.docs.length - 1 == index) {
                              WidgetsBinding.instance
                                  .addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
                                Provider.of<TotalAmount>(context,
                                        listen: false)
                                    .display(totalAmount);
                              });
                            }
                            return storeSourceInfo(model, context,
                                removeCartFunction: () =>
                                    removeItemFromuserCart(
                                        model.shortInfo));
                          },
                          childCount: snapshot.hasData
                              ? snapshot.data.docs.length
                              : 0,
                        ),
                      );
          },
        )
```

with this code I am creating a sharedPreferences list named "userCartList" which gets updated with the uniqueId "shortInfo" every time cart button is added which then query the saved list of "shortInfo" with my products database which return a stream .